# Mat Paginator not working with FormArray on Material Table

Tags: angular-material, angular7, mat-table, mat-pagination

I am using mat-table with formArray in it, also I need to Mat-paginator.

But unfortunately pagination not working.

[Stackbltiz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-editable-table-m91inp?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Sample Source,

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" formArrayName="dates">
    <!-- Row definitions -->
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i = index; columns: displayColumns;"></tr>

    <!-- Column definitions -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="from">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> From </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index"  [formGroupName]="index"> 
        <input type="date" formControlName="from" placeholder="From date">
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="to">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> To </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index"  [formGroupName]="index">
        <input type="date" formControlName="to" placeholder="To date">
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
  <button type="button" (click)="addRow()">Add row</button>
</form>

<pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
```

.Ts

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
      displayColumns = ['from', 'to'];
      form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({ 'dates': this.fb.array([]) });

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }

      get dateFormArray():FormArray {
        return this.form.get('dates') as FormArray;
      }

      addRow() {
        const row = this.fb.group({
          'from'   : null,
          'to'     : null
        });
        this.dateFormArray.push(row);
        this.dataSource.data =  this.dateFormArray.controls;
      }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually there are two issues:

1. `mat-paginator` element reference issue in `@ViewChild`
2. Getting Actual Index for `MatDataSource` (because you are having two data structure to list data `dataSource` and `FormArray` )

solution for first issue is to import paginator and mat-datasource like this

```
import { MatPaginator } from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
```

for second issue you have to get actual index like this:

```
getActualIndex(index : number)    {
    return index + this.paginator.pageSize * this.paginator.pageIndex;
}
```

and use `[formGroupName]="getActualIndex(index)"`

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-editable-table-97rd6a)

Also you can increase page size in drop down as per you add element in formArray.

Comment: This is not controlling to data, Its only adding page numbers

Comment: the 2nd part saved my life